# How do i call function in functional component - ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to call a function in functional component, Please check the code snippet below

```
import React from 'react';
 
const Users = () => {
  const greeting = 'Hello Function Component!';

  onUpdate = (name, age) => event =>  {
    // .....
  }

  onUserChange = (name, id) => {
   // Here i want to call the function onUpdate(name, age)
  }
 
  return (
      <select onChange={onUserChange}>
       // .....
      </select>
  );
};
 
export default Users;
```

Please suggest me to call the function onUpdate(name, age) in reactjs functional component.

Comment: Just like you call any function in JS. `onUpdate(...);`. But do add `const` before you functions to avoid creating globals.

Answer (score 0):

Just like what @Gabriele said in the comments

```
import React from 'react';
 
const Users = () => {
  const greeting = 'Hello Function Component!';  
  
  // Added const to avoid redeclaration or reassignment of any function
  const onUpdate = (name, age) => event =>  {
    // .....
  }

  const onUserChange = (name, id) => {
     onUpdate(name, age)
  }
 
  return (
      <select onChange={onUserChange}>
       // .....
      </select>
  );
};
 
export default Users;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember the syntax:

{FunctionName(parameters)}

That's it , But there is a little twist here. The above calling is done only of you have some code which will call this function.

But if you want your function to get called by itself as soon as it the screen renders, you have to use ( ) in the last.

Syntax: {funcName( )} the empty pair of parenthesis will call it as soon as the line executes.